# Apache is running but not can't connect remotely

Tags: windows, spring-boot, tomcat8

I am running Tomcat 8.5.56 in Windows Server 2016 with port 8040 but I am unable to browse it locally. 
eg. Server IP  192.168.1.20

Client IP  10.0.10.15

Answer (score 2):

first check the server side:

on the Windows Server 2016 ,test with browser 127.0.0.1:8040, 192.168.1.20:8040

then check the client side:

```
ping -c5 192.168.1.20

nc -vz 192.168.1.20 8040 (linux)

telnet 192.168.1.20 8040 (windows)
```

possibly windows firewall?

Comment: yes it worked now. I changed path to C:\ProgramFiles\ and added access in windows firewall.